# Fan not working on a Thinkpad with Ubuntu 22.04.2; sensors -> fan1: 0 RPM

Tags: 22.04, thinkpad, fan, temperature

I have a small problem on a Lenovo P15 laptop. I noticed the plastic of the case has kind of 'melted' on its back.

I was then surprised no typical fan sound was audible!

Curious, I installed `sensors` and checked for it:

```sh
$ sensors --version
sensors version 3.6.0 with libsensors version 3.6.0

$ sensors
iwlwifi_1-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +67.0°C  

nouveau-pci-0100
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:            N/A  (high = +95.0°C, hyst =  +3.0°C)
                       (crit = +105.0°C, hyst =  +5.0°C)
                       (emerg = +135.0°C, hyst =  +5.0°C)

BAT0-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
in0:          12.88 V  

thinkpad-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
fan1:           0 RPM
CPU:          +77.0°C  
GPU:              N/A  
temp3:        +76.0°C  
temp4:         +0.0°C  
temp5:        +77.0°C  
temp6:        +77.0°C  
temp7:        +78.0°C  
temp8:            N/A  

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +76.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:        +77.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:        +79.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:        +82.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:        +81.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

nvme-pci-0400
Adapter: PCI adapter
Composite:    +69.9°C  (low  = -273.1°C, high = +83.8°C)
                       (crit = +84.8°C)
Sensor 1:     +69.9°C  (low  = -273.1°C, high = +65261.8°C)
Sensor 2:     +69.9°C  (low  = -273.1°C, high = +65261.8°C)

acpitz-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
temp1:        +72.0°C  (crit = +128.0°C)
 +72.0°C  (crit = +128.0°C)
```

I also installed `lm-sensors` and run `sensor-detect`. This allows me to add the following to `/etc/modules` after the procedure:

```
~$ cat /etc/modules
# /etc/modules: kernel modules to load at boot time.
#
# This file contains the names of kernel modules that should be loaded
# at boot time, one per line. Lines beginning with "#" are ignored.


# Generated by sensors-detect on Thu Mar 16 23:46:51 2023
# Chip drivers
coretemp

$ /etc/init.d/kmod start
```

```sh
$ apt-cache policy lm-sensors
lm-sensors:
  Installed: 1:3.6.0-7ubuntu1
  Candidate: 1:3.6.0-7ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 1:3.6.0-7ubuntu1 500
        500 http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

I rebooted but nothing changed. The fan stays idle even on high load.

What causes the fan to stop and how could I get it back to work?

##### Information

```
OS: Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS x86_64 
Host: 20W6004XMZ ThinkPad P15s Gen 2i 
Kernel: 5.19.0-35-generic 
CPU: 11th Gen Intel i7-1165G7 (8) @ 4.700GHz 
GPU: NVIDIA Quadro T500 Mobile 
GPU: Intel TigerLake-LP GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics] 
Memory: 4592MiB / 31824MiB
```

```
$ sudo systemctl status thermald.service
○ thermald.service - Thermal Daemon Service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/thermald.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead) since Fri 2023-03-17 00:18:17 CET; 13h ago
   Main PID: 1082 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
        CPU: 6ms

mar 17 00:18:17 laptop-ThinkPad systemd[1]: Starting Thermal Daemon Service...
mar 17 00:18:17 laptop-ThinkPad thermald[1082]: 27 CPUID levels; family:model:stepping 0x6:8c:1 (6:140:1)
mar 17 00:18:17 laptop-ThinkPad thermald[1082]: [/sys/devices/platform/thinkpad_acpi/dytc_lapmode] present: Thermald can't run on this platform
mar 17 00:18:17 laptop-ThinkPad thermald[1082]: Unsupported cpu model or platform
mar 17 00:18:17 laptop-ThinkPad systemd[1]: thermald.service: Deactivated successfully.
mar 17 00:18:17 laptop-ThinkPad systemd[1]: Started Thermal Daemon Service._
```

Also, in the "Power" menu of the "Settings":
[image]

```sh
$ grep MHz /proc/cpuinfo 
cpu MHz     : 1137.014
cpu MHz     : 922.759
cpu MHz     : 1127.838
cpu MHz     : 1255.019
cpu MHz     : 1159.533
cpu MHz     : 521.957
cpu MHz     : 1246.749
cpu MHz     : 1263.212
```

*Normal usage.*

```sh
$ grep MHz /proc/cpuinfo 
cpu MHz     : 3959.109
cpu MHz     : 3959.044
cpu MHz     : 3959.019
cpu MHz     : 3959.131
cpu MHz     : 3959.134
cpu MHz     : 3959.043
cpu MHz     : 3958.995
cpu MHz     : 3959.111
```

*After running `stress --cpu 8`.*

Well, this is actually strange that it is blocked at 3'960 MHz whereas it can run up to `4700.0000` as reported by `lscpu` (?)

Comment: My first bet would be a hardware problem, but the temperatures you show are not _that_ high which is also weird. Please add the output of `systemctl status thermald.service` to you question. Also try `sudo apt install thinkfan` to install the thinkpad fan tool. You might also want to check out https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Fan_speed_control#ThinkPad_laptops

Comment: @terdon thanks. Information added. I'm exploring this `thinkfan` package, it seems promising....

Comment: Do you also notice that the machine is running very slowly? Is your CPU throttled? See [CPU freq locked to 800mhz shortly after boot (ps15 thinkpad)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/737267) and my notes (sorry, very unclear, they're notes for me) on the things I tried for my machine: https://gist.github.com/terdon/e1dc9cdec58d0351a0f6bbeb0051474b

Comment: No it's not slow, well, not that I know actually. I also added information on CPU speeds under a normal load and when running `stress` on all cores.

Comment: Yeah, so you are throttled, but not much. Interesting. My P14s was much, much more throttled, but I don't use Ubuntu so it could be that Ubuntu ships with a better configuration for these machines.